# Valid characters in custom data- attribute name in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating some custom `data-*` attributes in my site and I am having a hard time reading the Spec [Here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#before-attribute-name-state) and [Here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes).

I can tell `[a-z], [0-9] and '-'` are allowed but I can't decipher anything more from that.

I also think `"A-Z"` will automatically converted to lower ( Spec link 1) before being processed but it mentions not using them. ( Spec link 2)

### Questions:

1) What characters are allowed and not allowed in a custom `data-*` attribute?

2) Are special characters like `'_', '!', '$', etc.` allowed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From your spec link 2, the allowed characters come from the Name production in XML, which is, given that the attribute already starts with `data-`

```
":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] |
[#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | 
[#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF] | "-" |
"." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
```

`_` is explicitly listed as OK

`!` (#x21) and `$` (#x24) are not allowed

Spec link 1 is irrelevant. That's for user-agents, to describe how the characters should be processed, regardless of whether they are valid or not.

Comment: So if I'm reading what you listed here correctly. `":","_","."and "-"` are the only valid special characters?

Comment: Define "special". There's lots more outside the ASCII range.

Comment: Note that you probably want to avoid `:` too, to avoid confusion with the namespace prefix delimiter in XML.

Comment: Anything in [`this`](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif) image between Dec 32 - Dec 126 that aren't `[a-z][A-Z] or [0-9]`. What co-works of mine would call the "common" special character set.

Comment: Heh OK. It's time to move on from ASCII :-)

Comment: If you're using javascript to access the attribute name, you may want to avoid '-', since (e.g. for event handling) this ends up with event.target.dataset.my-attribute, which is evaluated as a 'minus', so needs extra dereferencing...i.e. (not tested) event.target.dataset['my-attribute'].

Comment: @AndyS, No, you just camelCase it like this event.target.dataset.myAttribute.  This is in the spec.